# Which keys are XF86Back and XF86Forward in EMACS?

Tags: emacs

It seems that emacs binds some useful commands to these two keys, but I do not know which keys are these on Windows. So, does any one knows these keys?

Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is actually C-x Forward (right cursor arrow) and C-x Back (left cursor arrow)

Comment: Thank you. Who is the nut who came up with XF86Back and XF86Forward? That is about as discoverable as naming it after some random Pokémon. They might be Pokémon...

Comment: uchuugaka - They're keysyms named by the XFree86 project. Presumably, the XF86 prefix is to avoid conflicts with other named keys.

Answer (score 28):

`XF86Back`, `XF86Forward` are multimedia keys supported by XOrg see complete list [here](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols). AFAIK these can be bound to different keys depending on your keyboard

In this particular case, the commands bound to `XF86Back` are also bound to `C-x <C-left>`, `C-x <left>`, these keys run the command `previous-buffer`. Similarly the keys `XF86Forward`, `C-x <C-right>`, `C-x <right>` are bound to `next-buffer`[1].

In general to know about a keybinding in emacs, you should do `C-h k <keybinding>` this will popup a `*Help*` with information about the command the key runs. Sometimes you may not know what the exact keys are like in your case `XF86Forward`, in such situation you can do `M-: (describe-key <keybinding>) RET` for getting help eg. `M-: (describe-key (kbd "<XF86Forward>")) RET` will provide you help about the command bound to key as well as the alternate keybindings. Remember `describe-*` commands are your friends :)

[1] The keybindings are applicable only in normal buffers, different commands are run in `info` buffers.

Comment: When your key is in a menu, like `XF86Back` and `XF86Forward` which are in the buffer menu, so you can do `C-h k` select the menu with the mouse, and get all the bindings for this action.

Answer (score 1):

Since the extra media/program keys present on some keyboards often have global functions assigned, Emacs on Windows does not use them by default.  If you want it to, then you need to set `w32-pass-multimedia-buttons-to-system` to `nil`.

This will make those keys available as `browser-back` and `browser-forward` or perhaps `media-previous` and `media-next`, depending on your keyboard.